# Tooltip Position Breaking on Scrolling Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve a **Sidebar** with **Tooltip** attach to its `<li>` elements like this:
[Screenshot - Good Tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0nPn.png)

But whenever I scroll down to the bottom of the sidebar, The **Tooltip** position is breaking and is not sticking to its `<li>` element: [Screenshot - Bad Tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g07xc.png).

Here is the : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranaigiri/v4L9o2k5/7/).

Your Idea and Suggestion would be really appreciated. Thank You!

**UPDATE:**
So, I've followed the advice from the comment and used the scrollbar height to adjust the Tooltip position using JS. Here's the updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranaigiri/L2cv5wq3/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Your tooltips elements have absolute positioning, with top property related to the body, not to their li parent.
On loading, top value is OK, as calculated from the elements flow, but get wrong as you scroll, as it won't change...

Comment: Thank you so much. I have used the scrollbar height to align the Tooltip position, Now its working as expected.

Comment: Happy to hear ! Dont' hesitate to upvote :)